# NOSQL GetByKey & Order

Tags: database, performance, nosql, berkeley-db

Now my architecture is based on Berkeley DB but doesn't perform well and it's not easy to clusterize.

I'm looking for a NOSQL database to store key/value data clusterizable and with best performance on get next key ordered and get by key.

There are no difference for me on RAM or persistence storage.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question for tips: [Hierarchical, ordered, key-value store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450684/hierarchical-ordered-key-value-store)

Also, there is a Google project looks promising: https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/ - I haven't used it, I'm just found it looking for similar NoSQL DB engine.